# Debugging Coldfusion Query with cfloop inside

Tags: sql, loops, coldfusion, cfquery

I'm trying to debug a cf query and cannot do this because of his complex structure.The code is following:

```
<cfquery name="qQuery" datasource="#variables.datasource#">
    <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#ArrayLen(aSQL)#" step="1">
        <cfif IsSimpleValue(aSQL[i])>
            <cfset temp = aSQL[i]>#Trim(DMPreserveSingleQuotes(temp))#
        <cfelseif IsStruct(aSQL[i])>
            <cfset aSQL[i] = queryparam(argumentCollection=aSQL[i])>
            <cfswitch expression="#aSQL[i].cfsqltype#">
                <cfcase value="CF_SQL_BIT">
                    #getBooleanSqlValue(aSQL[i].value)#
                </cfcase>
                <cfcase value="CF_SQL_DATE,CF_SQL_DATETIME">
                    #CreateODBCDateTime(aSQL[i].value)#
                </cfcase>
                <cfdefaultcase>
                    <!--- <cfif ListFindNoCase(variables.dectypes,aSQL[i].cfsqltype)>#Val(aSQL[i].value)#<cfelse> --->
                    <cfqueryparam value="#aSQL[i].value#" cfsqltype="#aSQL[i].cfsqltype#" maxlength="#aSQL[i].maxlength#" scale="#aSQL[i].scale#" null="#aSQL[i].null#" list="#aSQL[i].list#" separator="#aSQL[i].separator#">
                    <!--- </cfif> --->
                </cfdefaultcase>
            </cfswitch>
        </cfif>                     
    </cfloop>               
</cfquery>
```

If I run `<cfdump var="#qQuery#">` it's not working nor cfoutput, I get undefined qQuery error. How can I find what query is executing behind ? I don't want to use MS SQL profiler.

Thanks,

Comment: Out of context, that is a scary-looking way to build a query! Can you provide a sample of `aSQL`? That would make it much easier to parse, mentally.

Comment: Agree with @beercodebeer - but I think his problem is he can't actually produce the regular SQL the query is supposed to execute because his CFML is messing up the syntax. He's trying to get started on debugging, which is why I suggested `cftry` below.

Comment: What precisely are you trying to debug? Is the query crashing when you run it? Is it just not acting as you expect? If you can't dump the query, that indicates something pretty deep must be going wrong.

Comment: Run your page with debugging turned on.  Among other things, you will see if the query actually runs.  Based on your error message, it probably didn't.

Comment: Try/catch is a very fundamental troubleshooting tool and debugging 101. If you are new to CF/programming, start by reviewing the [error handling](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0bb9b-7ffe.html) section in the documentation.  Also, PreserveSingleQuotes makes your database vulnerable to SQL injection.  Read up on cfqueryparam.

Answer (score 2):

Take everything inside the query and wrap it in a cfsavecontent instead. Output that result.

If you place the cfsavecontent *inside* the cfquery tags, you don't even need to worry about the cfqueryparam tags barfing, although you do need to re-output that saved content inside the query. See http://coldflint.blogspot.com/2016/01/debugging-queries-dirty-way.html

Basically, you should have this:

```
<cfquery name="qQuery" datasource="#variables.datasource#">
    <cfsavecontent variable="sqlContent">
        <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#ArrayLen(aSQL)#" step="1">
            <cfif IsSimpleValue(aSQL[i])>
                <cfset temp = aSQL[i]>#Trim(DMPreserveSingleQuotes(temp))#
            <cfelseif IsStruct(aSQL[i])>
                <cfset aSQL[i] = queryparam(argumentCollection=aSQL[i])>
                <cfswitch expression="#aSQL[i].cfsqltype#">
                    <cfcase value="CF_SQL_BIT">
                        #getBooleanSqlValue(aSQL[i].value)#
                    </cfcase>
                    <cfcase value="CF_SQL_DATE,CF_SQL_DATETIME">
                        #CreateODBCDateTime(aSQL[i].value)#
                    </cfcase>
                    <cfdefaultcase>
                        <!--- <cfif ListFindNoCase(variables.dectypes,aSQL[i].cfsqltype)>#Val(aSQL[i].value)#<cfelse> --->
                        <cfqueryparam value="#aSQL[i].value#" cfsqltype="#aSQL[i].cfsqltype#" maxlength="#aSQL[i].maxlength#" scale="#aSQL[i].scale#" null="#aSQL[i].null#" list="#aSQL[i].list#" separator="#aSQL[i].separator#">
                        <!--- </cfif> --->
                     </cfdefaultcase>
                 </cfswitch>
             </cfif>                     
         </cfloop>               
    </cfsavecontent>
    #sqlContent#
</cfquery>

<pre>#sqlContent#</pre>
```

Do make sure to put everything back to normal once you're done debugging.

Comment: (Edit) Good idea, but unfortunately CF will balk at trying to use cfqueryparam outside a cfquery tag.  You may have to resort to tricks like replacing the `<` in `<cfqueryparam` with the html equivalent `&lt` for it to work. Very klunky, but I have had to resort to that when debugging monster legacy apps ...

Comment: Yes, very clunky, and it will require a little manual editing, but it's probably the fastest move at this point.

Comment: I did a little investigation based on @Leigh 's comment, and found a better workaround (admittedly, this is all workaround), and updated my comment accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately, that will not *quite* work either. CF will see any single quotes embedded in the string (such as with createODBCDateTime) and helpfully escape them, thus breaking the SQL. Honestly, I would just copy and paste the code inside the cfquery, escape the query params, and dump it out on screen. Then go from there.  It is duplication, but is probably as good as it gets without cfscript. Having said all that, the original question is *very* ambiguous. Until the asker provides more specific information on the error and what is being debugged all we can do is guess... Voting to close.

Comment: Just my 2¢, but this is exactly why dynamic sql always *seems* like a great idea, but in reality, not so much ;-) It is difficult to do well, and troubleshooting problems is always more time consuming than you expect.

Comment: Tried and have the following : Message: faultCode:Server.Processing faultString:'Unable to invoke CFC - Variable SQLCONTENT is undefined.' faultDetail:''

Answer (score 1):

If this question is more about HOW to debug or get some output you can work with, `cftry` and `cfcatch` are your friends.

```
<cftry>

---code logic---

<cfcatch>
<cfdump var="#cfcatch#">
</cfcatch>
</cfctry>
```

This should provide a complete dump of whatever errors ColdFusion encounters as well as SQL statements that were attempted, if there is indeed a syntax error generated by the loopy logic.

Comment: He can achieve the same result with normal debugging.  Besides, in this case, the error is an undefined variable, which changes the troubleshooting approach.

Comment: You're the best man! Uou helped me alot. Actually <cftry> should be putted between <cfquery> and <cfloop>, not outside <cfquery>.Thanks alot man!

Comment: Ha, I was beginning to think with all the other answers I was way off base. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to work from the inside out this.

As I look at this query, I note that it is split on `IsSimpleValue()` and `IsStruct()`. So run this

```
 <cfquery name="qQuery" datasource="#variables.datasource#">
    <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#ArrayLen(aSQL)#" step="1">
       <cfif IsSimpleValue(aSQL[i])>
            <cfset temp = aSQL[i]>#Trim(DMPreserveSingleQuotes(temp))#
       </cfif>                     
    </cfloop>               
 </cfquery>
```

Note that temp is never used.

The rest of the code creates `<cfqueryparam>`s

**Conclusion**

This code cannot work. It cannot create valid SQL.

Comment: it's not working :(  I also putted the debugger and I don't understand why I have for sql something like : [INSERT INTO [Properties_ClientCompanies] (, [property_uid], ,, [client_company_uid], ,, [company_role_uid], ,, [relationship_start], ,, [is_active], ,, [created_by], ,, [created_date], ,, [modified_by], ,, [modified_date], ), VALUES (, {NULL=no, SEPARATOR=,, PrimaryKey=false, CFSQLTYPE=CF_SQL_IDSTAMP, AllowNulls=NO, VALUE=F812D675-AE0C-898A-3851-753EDC7853D2, MAXLENGTH=<<Recursive Reference - Cannot display value>>...

Answer (score 0):

Your error has nothing to do with the sql being generated by the code in the cfquery block.  It's an undefined variable.  If there was a problem with the code you displayed, the error message would be different.

Troublehoot as follows.  First comment out all the code inside that query and replace it with:

```
select 1 record
```

This is valid for MS SQL.  Leave everything else unchanged.

Running the page will produce the same error.  You then have to determine why the query is not running.  Likely, you have something like this going on:

```
<cfif some Condition is met>
run the query
</cfif>
dump the query
```

You'll have to determine why your condition wasn't met and make sure your page runs properly when it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to put `<cftry>` outside `<cfloop>` but not outside `<cfquery>`.I found that I forgot to send one parametter.

So the code is following:

```
        <cfquery name="qQuery" datasource="#variables.datasource#">
                    <cftry>             
                        <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#ArrayLen(aSQL)#" step="1">
                            <cfif IsSimpleValue(aSQL[i])>
                                <cfset temp = aSQL[i]>#Trim(DMPreserveSingleQuotes(temp))#                          
                            <cfelseif IsStruct(aSQL[i])>
                                <cfset aSQL[i] = queryparam(argumentCollection=aSQL[i])>
                                <cfswitch expression="#aSQL[i].cfsqltype#">
                                    <cfcase value="CF_SQL_BIT">
                                        #getBooleanSqlValue(aSQL[i].value)#
                                    </cfcase>
                                    <cfcase value="CF_SQL_DATE,CF_SQL_DATETIME">
                                        #CreateODBCDateTime(aSQL[i].value)#
                                    </cfcase>
                                    <cfdefaultcase>                                     
                                        <cfqueryparam value="#aSQL[i].value#" cfsqltype="#aSQL[i].cfsqltype#" maxlength="#aSQL[i].maxlength#" scale="#aSQL[i].scale#" null="#aSQL[i].null#" list="#aSQL[i].list#" separator="#aSQL[i].separator#">                                      
                                    </cfdefaultcase>
                                </cfswitch>
                            </cfif>                 
                        </cfloop>
                        <cfcatch>
                            <cfdump var="#cfcatch#" >
                        </cfcatch>
                    </cftry>                            
                </cfquery
```